# Using the Compactness Theorem for Propositional Logic to prove that the countable union of countable sets is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus

Consider a disjoint family $\{A_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of countable sets, let $A$ denote the their union. We can define a language $L$ to have atoms $p_{an}$ for each $a\in A$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (expressing *$a$ is assigned the number $n$* when true). Then we define $S$ to be the set of $L$ formulas:

1. $\displaystyle\bigvee_{n\in\mathbb{N}}p_{an}$ for all $a\in A$. (each $a\in A$ is assigned at least one number)
2. $\neg(p_{an}\wedge p_{am})$ for all $a\in A$ and $n\neq m\in\mathbb{N}$ (each $a\in A$ is assigned at most one number).
3. $\neg(p_{an}\wedge p_{bn})$ for all $a\neq b\in A$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (no two distinct elements of $A$ are assigned to the same number)

If $S$ is satisfiable, then we can use an $L$-assignment $M$ satisfying $S$ to define an injective function $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by $f(a) = n$ iff $M(p_{am})=\mbox{T}$. It is well defined by 1. and 2. and injective by 3.

Now, if $S_{0}\subseteq S$ is finite, then the elements of $A$ mentioned in $S_{0}$ are finitely many, say $x_{1},\ldots,x_{k}$ and we can simply define an $L$-assignment $M$ by $M(p_{x_{i}m})=\mbox{T}$ iff $i=m$. Then $M$ satisfies $S_{0}$ and as a result $S$ is finitely satisfiable. By Compactness, $S$ is satisfiable and we are done.

Or aren't we? It seems I am missing something important here...at no point I seem to utilize that the family is countable...

---

Edit: As it is pointed out in a comment below by Timo, the argument is flawed. However, is it possible to use Compactness to prove the well known result?

What if we modify 1. above so that the disjunction is finite? Namely,

1'. $\displaystyle{\bigvee_{n\in F}} p_{an}$ for all $a\in A$ and finite $F\subset\mathbb{N}$.

Thus $S$ would be the set of all the $L$-formulas from 1'., 2. and 3.

Would this work?

Comment: Your first formula (the big disjunction) has infinite length, and therefore is not a formula of classical propositional logic. Hence compactness does not apply here. In fact, you argument shows that the compactness theorem fails in an extension of propositional logic which has infinite disjunctions, as otherwise you could indeed prove that every set is countable.

Comment: I see, thank you. Is not possible then to use compactness to show that the countable union of countable sets is countable? I guess if it was possible to use compactness the result would be equivalent to the finite union of finite sets.

Comment: Your proposal in the edit doesn't work because the sentences of type 1' are too strong; the resulting $S$ is unsatisfiable.

Comment: You could replace the infinite disjunction with something like "$\exists n.p_a(n)$", but then you'd have to include an axiomatization of the naturals, and you'd only end up proving that there's *some* model of that axiomatization with cardinality $|A|$, which tells us nothing about $|A|$ due to the [Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem).

Comment: I'd try using $p_{i,j,k}$ meaning "element $j$ of $A_i$ is assigned index $k$", and replace your infinite disjunction with finite ones that "leave enough room" to ensure satisfiability, e.g. $\bigvee_{k=1}^{(i+j)^2}p_{i,j,k}$ for each $i,j\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: @Karl Thank you for your comments. I take it you mean "too strong" in the sense that with 1'. there are too many formulas in $S$? Also, is there a reason why you made $k$ range between $1$ and $(i+j)^{2}$? Why not simply $(i+j)$? I am not entirely sure what you mean by "leave enough room"

Comment: With your 1', you have e.g. both $p_{a1}\lor p_{a2}$ and $p_{a3}\lor p_{a4}$, which together with the sentences of type 2 are inconsistent.

Comment: I picked $(i+j)^2$ to ensure that every finite subset of $S$ is satisfiable. A different bound might work, but you'll see the issue when you try to prove it - there's a finite counting argument involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Karl in the comments for pointing me in the right direction.

We define a language $L$ to have atoms $p_{ij}^{n}$ for each $i,j,n\in\mathbb{N}$ (expressing when true: *the $i^{th}$ element of $A_{j}$ (denoted by $a_{ij}$) is assigned the number $n$*). Then we define $S$ to be the set of $L$ formulas:

1. $\displaystyle\bigvee_{n=1}^{N_{ij}}p_{ij}^{n}$ for all $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$, where $N_{ij}$ will be an appropriate natural number. (Each $a_{ij}$ is assigned at least one number)
2. $\neg(p_{ij}^{n}\wedge p_{ij}^{m})$ for all $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n\neq m\in\mathbb{N}$. (Each $a_{ij}$ is assigned at most one number).
3. $\neg(p_{ij}^{n}\wedge p_{uv}^{n})$ for all $(i,j)\neq(u,v)$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. (No two distinct elements $a_{ij}$ and $a_{uv}$ are assigned the same number)

Now, if $S_{0}\subseteq S$ is finite, then the elements of $A$ mentioned in $S_{0}$ form a finite subset $B=\{a_{i,j}:\mbox{finitely many $i,j$}\}$ of $A$. Now, we can define a function $g:B\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$

$$g(a_{ij})=3^{i}5^{j}.$$

The function $g$ is injective by the uniqueness of prime factorization. Therefore, if we let $N_{ij}=5^{i+j}$ in 1. we can define an $L$-assignment $M$ by

$$M(p_{ij}^{n})=\mbox{T} \;\;\mbox{iff}\;\; g(a_{ij})=n.$$

$M$ satisfies $S_{0}$ and so $S$ is finitely satisfiable. By Compactness, $S$ is satisfiable.

Finally, we can use any $L$-assignment $M$ satisfying $S$ to define a function $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by

$$f(a) = n \;\;\mbox{iff}\;\; M(p_{ij}^{n})=\mbox{T},$$

which is well defined by 1. and 2., and injective by 3.

Note: $N_{ij}$ in 1. has to be large enough to allow us to prove that $S$ is finitely satisfiable, which in turn depends on the function $g$. That is, it will depend on the indices $i,j$ and we want $N_{ij}>g(a_{ij})$. Notice that we may define the function $g$ differently. Karl in the comments suggested $(i+j)^{2}$ possibly because he was thinking of $g(a_{ij})=\binom{i+j+1}{2}+j$. For this $g$, letting $N_{ij}=(i+j+1)^{2}$ would certainly suffice. (If we work with $\mathbb{N}^{+}$ we may also use $g(a_{ij}) = 2^{i-1}(2j-1)$, in which case $N=2^{i+j}$ will suffice.

Comment: Nice! I didn't think of directly defining $g$ - I just had a counting argument justifying that it can be done element by element. Your way is simpler!

Comment: It's also worth noting that compactness isn't actually doing much useful work here, since we're using the same $g$ for every $S_0$ - we've just directly given an injection $\Bbb N^2\to\Bbb N$.